# When is the "the" necessary?

Tags: definite-article

I have the following sentence:

> *Successfully ran **the** "user.js" seed.*

Is that "*the*" necessary?

---

When is it necessary and when is it not?

Comment: It's necessary whenever you have a noun after the name. Observe: Successfully read War and Peace. Successfully watched Heat. Successfully ran user.js. But: Successfully read the War and Peace book. Successfully watched the Heat movie. Successfully ran the user.js seed. The "the" belongs to the noun after the name, and having the noun there but not having the "the" would be ungrammatical. But if you drop the noun, you drop the article, too. (Unless of course, there's a "the" in the name itself, like Successfully read The Observer, or Successfully watched The Fugitive.)

Comment: Thanks! If you want to create an answer, I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the definite article is needed because you are being specific.

> I successfully ran the "user.js" seed.

You ran a seed. *Which seed?* The "user.js" seed. If you can ask "*which...*" then there must be more than one and you need to be more specific, using the definite article.

If the article you are referring to has a unique name then there is no need for the definite article. Sticking with your computing scenario, consider this example:

> Open Device Manager.

"Device Manager" is a proper noun for an extension of the Microsoft Management Console. There is only one Device Manager on your computer, so there is no need for the definite article. Nobody can rightly ask "*which device manager?*"

However, if you said:

> Open the Device Manager console window.

Here, the definite article *is* required, because you are referring to its console window, and there are lots of console windows.

Open the console window. *Which console window?* The Device Manager console window.

Comment: Do you think run a seed is something the common mortal gets?